# .Net - ado.net importing rows vs adding rows?

Tags: .net, ado.net, datatable

The DataTable has a method called ImportRow(), There is also a method unders the rows called Add(). So what's the difference between these methods?

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

vs

```
dataTable.ImportRow(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ImportRow preserves any setting of the row: DataRowState,values etc.
- Add calls NewRow that initialize a row using default values.

ImportRow is useful if you're importing a row from another table and you need to preserve all because you're planning to use a DataAdapter